# Binding data from view to controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

Hello I am building an angular application and I have a problem inside my stripe form. Basically I send data such as card number, expiry date and CVC code from the view to the controller's stripe callback, but I would like to add also the amount of money to pay. So I added this into my form:

```
<form stripe-form="handleStripe" name="myForm">
    <!-- input added for the price -->
    <div class="row" ng-if="!unregistered_user">
        <div class="input-field col col-xs-12">
            <label for="name">Amount </label>
            <input name='price' type="number" id="amount" ng-model="price">
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- credit/debit card form -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col col-xs-12">
            <label for="cardn">Card number</label>
            <input type="text" name="number" id="cardn"  ng-model="number" payments-validate="card" payments-format="card" payments-type-model="type" ng-class="myForm.number.$card.type"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col-xs-6">
            <label for="exp">Expiry</label>
            <input type="text" id="exp" ng-model="expiry" payments-validate="expiry" payments-format="expiry" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col-xs-6">
            <label for="cvc">CVC</label>
            <input type="text" id="cvc" ng-model="cvc" payments-validate="cvc" payments-format="cvc" payments-type-model="type"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Pay {{ price }}</button>
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

In the controller I have this variable:

```
▸   $scope.price = 0;
```

When I first load the page I can see that the price input has exactly the same amount that I put in the variable $scope.price. But when I changed it in the page and submit the form, $scope.price is always 0.
It's like the data is being passed from the controller to the view, but not the way back from the view to the controller.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is with ng-if that wraps your input with price model. ng-if creates its own scope and in your case the price is connected with the scope inside ng-if and not with you controller.
You could use ng-show instead, or set the model like this: ng-model = "$parent.price" or use controllerAs syntax and you don't have to worry about this issue anymore.

Comment: Oh god! How could I have missed that? Your are absolutely right, thank you!